# Angular Interceptor Ignore withCredentials: true

Tags: angular, interceptor, cookie-httponly

**Can't use conditions inside an interceptor for (req.url)?**

//THIS CODE WORK

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

       req = req.clone({
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      return next.handle(req);
}
```

//THIS CODE NOT WORK

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
 if (req.url.indexOf('/token/refresh') > -1) {
       req = req.clone({
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      return next.handle(req);
   }else{
      return next.handle(req);
   }
}
```

Is not being included the httponly secure cookies in the second code, and I don't see anything that makes this possible, since the condition of the second code is true, in theory the same thing is being executed with the only difference that there is a condition in the second code but this condition is true so there should be no problems.

This is executed once, so a second call that could change the result is not contemplated.

Please don't ask about CORS and configurations, all that is fine, it works with the first code and it doesn't work with the second one, logically it should work with both.

Comment: I use the context `if (req.context.get(BYPASS_LOG) === true) {...}` same, not work